# How to create manual mock with jest in nodejs app for mailgun-js?

Tags: node.js, jestjs, mailgun

code in app/src/emails/account.js

```
const mailgun = require("mailgun-js");
const DOMAIN = "sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mailgun.org";
const mg = mailgun({apiKey: process.env.MAILGUN_API_KEY, domain: DOMAIN});

const sendWelcomeEmail = async (email, name) => {
    const dataForMail = {
        to: email,
        from: 'zzz@xxx.com',
        subject: 'Testing!',
        text: `Welcome to the app, ${name}, let me know how you get along with the app.`,

    }

    mg.messages().send(dataForMail)

}
```

code in app/test/__mocks__/mailgun-js:

```
module.exports = {
    messages() {

    },
    send() {

    },
    mailgun() {

    }

}
```

Whenever I run jest, it says 'mailgun is not a function'. How can I create a manual mock for this constructor?

Comment: Note https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks.html#mocking-node-modules - *"adjacent to `node_modules/`"*.

Comment: I've placed it in an appropriate directory. It says, 'mailgun isn't a function', which means i've put it in proper file. When i intentionally rename the file from 'mailgun-js.js' to any other name, the test passes because it's not mocking that library. Can you help me edit the file so that the test gets passed?

Comment: Your mock is an object, not a function. Test doubles need to match the interface of the thing they're replacing; in this case, it needs to be a function that *returns* an object with a messages method (which returns an object with the send method). Your mock doesn't match that structure at all.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe for helping me out. I edited the mailgun-js.js the way you said and now it's working properly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My mock is an object, not a function. Test doubles need to match the interface of the thing they're replacing; in this case, it needs to be a function that returns an object with a messages method (which returns an object with the send method). My mock doesn't match that structure at all. (Big thanks to @jonrsharpe for informing this)
mailgun-js.js needs to be edited the same way.

```
module.exports = function(apiKey, domain) {
    const object2 = {
        send() {

        }
    }

    const object1 = {
        messages () {
            return object2
        }
    }
    return object1
}
```