# Incorporating mailgun into a controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mailgun

I have been trying to use mailgun. js to respond to a get request and when I move it out of my `routes` file and into a controller function, I know I am missing something. 
It works fine when I make a request to

```
const mailgun = require('mailgun.js');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
   const API_KEY = 'secret';
   const DOMAIN = 'secretdomain';
   const mg= mailgun({ apiKey: API_KEY, domain: DOMAIN });
   const data = {
     from: 'bob@thebuilder.com',
     to: 'barney@rubble.com',
     subject: 'Whats up doc',
     template: "reqfeedback",
   };
   mg.messages().send(data, function (error, body) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    console.log(body);
   }); 
});
```

but when I try to add it to my controller file as a function, I get an unhandled promise TypeError saying `mailgun is not a function`  so I made sure it's wrapped in a try/catch like so...

`controller.js`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mailgun = require('mailgun.js');

const sendEmail = async(req,res,next) => {
   try{
      const API_KEY = 'secret';
      const DOMAIN = 'secretdomain';
      const mg= mailgun({ apiKey: API_KEY, domain: DOMAIN });
      const data = {
          from: 'bob@thebuilder.com',
          to: 'barney@rubble.com',
          subject: 'Whats up doc',
          template: "reqfeedback",
      };
      await mg.messages().send(data, function (error, body) {
          if (error) {
            console.log(error);
       }
          console.log(body);
       });
  catch (err) {
    const error = new HttpError(
        'Something went wrong, could not send email.',
        500
    );
    return next(error);
    }
    res.status(200).json({ message: 'email sent' });
};

exports.sendEmail = sendEmail;
```

and I add this route:
`routes.js`

```
const controllers = require('../controllers/controllers');
const router = express.Router();
const express = require('express');

router.get('/sendEmail', controllers.sendEmail);

module.exports = router;
```

But when I send the get request I keep getting the 500 error  "message": "Something went wrong, could not request feedback."

Halp pls.

Comment: Can you investigte what `mailgun` is when using your controller file? Either through a breakpoint (and a debugger) or a simple `console.log`.

Comment: What if you remove the async keyword? Or maybe you should do new mailgun(yourconfig)

Comment: If I remove async/await I get "mailgun is not a function".

Comment: @abondoa pretty sure it is an object after seeing this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60360507/how-to-create-manual-mock-with-jest-in-nodejs-app-for-mailgun-js